# Converting seconds after epoch into unix time

Tags: c++

I have seconds (say x, x is long long data type) after epoch. I wish to convert it into unix time using `<ctime>` library. The issue is, I want a time_t variable for `gmtime()` to work, I am unable to make my `x` (`long long`) converted to `time_t`.

This is what am doing:

```
//x is number of seconds after epoch, I want that in unix time 
time_t t=x; 
printf("%s\n",asctime(gmtime(&t)));
```

Can I somehow typecast `x` into `time_t`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just cast it?

```
time_t t = (time_t) x;
```

It will cut of the top 32 bits but you still have over 25 years until you really need 64-bit timestamps. :)

Of course, there might be trouble if your epoch is not the same as the POSIX epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00).

Comment: That's what people back in the 70s thought, but year 2000 came anyway!

Comment: `time_t` *is* the type for storing seconds since epoch. Wheter the library in question handles it as a 32 or 64 bit value is up to the library. I.e., this is a (the?) perfectly valid answer. +1.

Comment: @Shahbaz I know, I was there! :) Thankfully I entered work-life late enough in the 90's that our team already had that one in mind. And it's also why I never use anything but the built-in time types and functions, then when the change comes to make `time_t` 64 bits my code will just need a recompile to work.

Comment: Please note `time_t` is *not* guaranteed to be in seconds.

Comment: @BoBTFish If you read the official POSIX reference for [`<sys/types.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/basedefs/sys/types.h.html#tag_13_67), then it specifically states that `time_t` is "Used for time in seconds."

Comment: I'm a bit confused here actually. I think it may not be guaranteed by the c standard, but is by the posix standard possibly? http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/systypes.h.html says `time_t Used for time in seconds.` Edit - Yes, about a minute slow there.

Comment: @BoBTFish Reading a [C11 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), section 7.27.1 paragraph 4, it states that "The range and precision of times representable in clock_t and time_t are
implementation-defined.". So you are right by the C standard. :)

Comment: actually after typecasting I printed value of x and t, and they weren't coming out to be same, so that caused whole confusion..
PS:
time_t t=x; //also works without typecasting

Comment: Yes, that's what I checked in the first place. But the question was specifically about unix time, so I guess posix is a safe assumption.